# HttpClientFactory and typed-client?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm new in implementing HttpClientFactory. I've read a document about ways to implement.
in my code there are services and its interfaces so I want to use typed-client. but I have a question?! in typed-client, we don't use HttpClientFactory directly **so where is the benefit of the HttpClientFactory?**
this is my code to register service:

```
var clientConf = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ClientConfigs));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IClientService, ClientService>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(clientConf.GetSection("EndPoint").Value);
 }).AddHttpMessageHandler<ServiceCallRequestHeader>();
```

this is ctor of my service:

```
  public ClientService(HttpClient client, ILogger<ClientService> logger)
    {
        _client = client;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Typed-Client, Dotnet uses HttpClientFactory to create the instance of `HttpClient`, using that instance they will create your client/class instance. So in the end, even if you are not using `HttpClientFactory` explicitly, you are using it.

Below is the internal code that does this
[image]
Source: [HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/HEAD/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs)